# Animating SVG gradient with Snap.svg

Tags: jquery, svg, snap.svg

I am trying to animate the gradient of a SVG using the Snap SVG library.
As of now i have something like that [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Cs8F/83/)

My Jquery code

```js
var animatingSvg = Snap('#wd_logo');
       console.log(animatingSvg);
       var g = animatingSvg.gradient("l(0, 0, 1, 1)#4057FF-#2DD9C0-black");
       animatingSvg.attr({
           fill : g
       })
       function anim () {
            g.attr({ x1: 1, y: 0, x2: 1, y2: 0 });
            g.animate({ x1: 1, y1: 100, x2: 0, y2: 100 }, 1500, mina.linear, anim);
        };
anim();
```

My purpose is to create a smooth filling effect inside the logo (default black color and then it gets filled)
Thank you.

Comment: Is there a question somewhere ? You have a typo in your first g.attr(), it should be y1 and not y.

Comment: well right now the color does not go all the way to the end.